# Program to read data from keyboard, write it to a file and again read the same data from the file and copy that to another file and display?

Tags: c, file-io, input, output

This is what I've so far. I want the program to read data from the keyboard write it to a file called INPUT, again read the same data from the INPUT file, and copy to that
another file and also display it on the screen.
I don't know where did I go wrong.
Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<file.h>
main()
{
  FILE *f1,*f2;
  char c;
  printf(“data input\n\n”)
  f1 = fopen(“INPUT”, “w”);
  while((c = getchar())!=EOF)
    putc(c,f1);
  fclose(f1);
  printf(“\ndata output\n\n”)
  f1 = fopen(“INPUT”, “r”);
  while((c = getchar())!=EOF)
    putc(“%c”,c);
  fclose(f1);
  //copying f f1 data into f2
  f1=fopen(file1,”r”)
  if(f1=NULL)
  {
    printf(“no data”);
    exit(0):
  }
  f2=fopen(file2,”w”);
  if(f2=null)
  {
    printf(“cannot able to open”);
    exit(0);
  }
  while((ch==getc(f1)!=EOF)
    putc(ch,f2);
  printf(“completed”);
  fclose(f1);
  fclose(f2);
}
```

Comment: Step through the code one line at a time and pay attention to what is written, read, and printed.

Comment: You didn't specify your problem, so I assume this doesn't compile. The `C` syntax is *case sensitive*. All you have to do is read the errors the compiler gives and **fix your code**.

Comment: After you get the lower/upper case mismatches fixed you should also add some comments above the sections where you 1) copy keyboard to INPUT and 2) copy INPUT to the other file and display. It will help you to do what @RaymondChen suggested.

Comment: Comments in C look like this /* comment here */ and the ones I suggest should be on a line of their own

Comment: Don't use a word processor to edit C code.  Your 'double quotes' are variously `“` (U+201C) and `”` (U+201D) instead of the expected `"` (ASCII 34, U+0022).  Also, `printf()` does not print out newlines unless you ask it to.  Most of your `printf()` calls should include at least a newline `\n` at the end of the format string.  When reporting errors about opening files, it is sensible to include the file name in the error report (it makes it much easier to find the problem if you know which file is causing the trouble).

Answer (score 1):

You want to compare with NULL:

```
  if(f1=NULL)
```

But this assigns NULL.

Same issue in another comparison:

```
  if(f2=null)
```

Simply change them to:

```
if(!f1)
```

and

```
if(!f2)
```